# how to control video output type with the vlc sdk in my c++ codes

Tags: c++, vlc, libvlc

I write a simple test case with libvlc to play a video, now i want to select the "windows GDI video output" when play media like what we do when use vlc player,  select the "windows GDI video output" in the tools->preferences->Video->Output item, then it can play the video on multi-screens smoothly, how can i implement it to select ""windows GDI video output" with libvlc sdk? can someone give me some help or example?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
const char * const vlc_args[] = {
  "--verbose", "1",
  "--vout", "wingdi",
  "-I", "dummy",
  "--ignore-config"
};
libvlc_instance_t *vlcInstance = libvlc_new(sizeof(vlc_args) / sizeof(vlc_args[0]), vlc_args);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. There is another problem.I use below command line to build a vlc rtsp stream server, and use vlc sdk to play it, but the player will freeze at the last frame, how to make the player play the rtsp netstream repeatedly without freezing ? 
vlc -vvv test.mp4 --sout-keep --sout "#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream}"